# regex back reference negative lookahead atomic group

Tags: php, regex, atomic, regex-lookarounds

I want to match a single or double quote mark, followed by any amount of characters that are not the character just matched, followed by one of the character matched:

```
"--'__'--"
```

Should match by the double quotes at each end.  However, I want the match to be possessive in that any characters that have already been tested should not be included in any future matches:

```
"--'__'--
```

Should *not* match because the double quote at the beginning is never followed by another one at the end.  I have come up with:

```
(?P<q>['"])(?>((?!(?P=q)).)*)(?P=q)
```

But this still matches my second string example above by the single quotes in the middle.  I don't understand why the atomic group doesn't accomplish this.  I have not been able to accomplish this with any other arrangement of atomic grouping either.

Also, if it is possible at all to match only the characters in between the quotes while asserting that the quotes are present that would be excellent.  Because lookbehind assertions are fixed width I can't use a back reference to assert that the captured group of either single or double quotes occurs prior to the negative lookahead.

Comment: Are your inputs only consisting of these or is there anything else? Is there a reason why your regex is not anchored?

Comment: @fge Good point.  This will probably be part of a larger expression unless I end up breaking everything down into smaller subexpressions.  I haven't worked with regexes too much and I'm not too sure how I would use anchors here.  Would a start anchor ensure that it would not "match in the middle" as in my second string?  If this expression was not matching at the start of the input, how does that change things?

Comment: Well, the beginning of line anchor ensures that the match can indeed only occur at the beginning. Can you try and add a `^` at the beginning and see how it behaves?

Comment: I have this regex which works: '^(['"])(((?!\1).)+)\1$' <-- no need for an atomic group, in fact you may use a possessive quantifier to achieve the same effect (replace `+` with `++`)

Comment: Ok...so it seems the only way to prevent it from matching the `'_'` within `"-'_'-` is to use a start anchor?  If so I will have to cut apart the input based on other criteria to use this subset at the start of a string.  Regarding the atomic group, correct me if I'm wrong - from my research I think `(?>expression*)` should be equivalent to `expression*+`? I thought the atomic group notation is preferred.

Comment: It is equivalent, yes. The atomic group has the advantage to be more universally supported and can encompass more than one repetition. You may also try and add a `\G` at the start instead of `^`. I'll try that.

Comment: Something keeps nagging at me telling me there's a way to do this without having to use the "start of string" limiter (normally the carat aka circumflex `^`)...that's why I was trying to use the atomic group.  As the regex engine proceeds, I want it to not backtrack after it consumes each character that is part of the "zero to many characters that are not the first captured group", so that after one time failing to match a closing quote, the entire expression fails.  Instead (using the star) on fail it backtracks past all of the dots consumed with negative lookahead and matches again.

Comment: There may be another solution: look for the first index of `"` and the first index of `'`, and depending on the lower one, try and match `"([^"]*)"` or `'([^']*)'`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be only one valid quoted substring per line, this may be a good starting point:

```php
<?php // test.php Rev:20120105_1800
// Return array of valid quoted substrings, one per line.
function getArrayOfOnePerLineValidQuotedSubstrings($text) {
    $re = '%
        # Match line w/1 valid "single" or "double" substring.
        ^               # Anchor to start of line.
        [^\'"]*         # Everything up to first quote.
        (?|             # Branch reset group $1: Contents.
          "([^"]*)"     # Either $1.1 Double quoted,
        | \'([^\']*)\'  # or $1.2 Single quoted contents.
        )               # End $1: branch reset group.
        [^\'"]*         # Everything after quoted sub-string.
        $               # Anchor to end of line.
        %xm';
    if (preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return array();
}
// Fetch test data from file.
$data = file_get_contents('testdata.txt');
// Get array of valid quoted substrings, one per line.
$output = getArrayOfOnePerLineValidQuotedSubstrings($data);
// Display results.
$count = count($output);
printf("%d matches found.\n", $count);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    printf("  match[%d] = {%s}\n", $i + 1, $output[$i]);
}
?>
```

This regex matches each line that contains one valid quoted substring and skips over lines that have invalid (i.e. `"--'__'--` which has an unbalanced double quoted substring) or no quoted substrings. For lines which match, the contents of the valid quoted substring are returned in group `$1`. The function returns an array of the matched substrings.

If your data will contain more than one substring per line, or if the quoted substrings or stuff between quoted substrings may contain escaped quotes, then a more complex solution may be formulated.